# Need a simple way to show a map from an address on .NET Compact Framework

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, mapping

Are there any easy and free methods of showing a map of a location starting from an the address in .NET Compact Framework.

I'm fine with opening IE Mobile from my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Map API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/), open the link in IE to show the location.

Note: This obviously requires internet access.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I missed the qualifier "free" in your original question, so this won't work.  My apologies.

You can make use of the Virtual Earth API to get a map and decorate it with pushpins.  I used it in a small project here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WiMoWifiPosition.aspx